# Returning parent attributes via sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am working on a `NodeJs` application using [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) as an ORM with exciting database , so I had to use [sequelize model generator](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) in order to generate the models for my application.
Here's an example of the generation output:

Category.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('category', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            field: 'id'
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'name'
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'category'
    });
};
```

Product.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('product', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            field: 'id'
        },
        category: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'category',
                key: 'id'
            },
            field: 'category'
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'name'
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'product'
    });
};
```

and then inside my controller I have this query :

```
models.product.findOne({
    where: {
        id: req.body.id
    }
}).then(function (obj) {
    //return the product data
    console.log(product.category) //works
    console.log(product.category.name) //return undefined
});
```

The question is how can I access to the parent table attribute via the same query `findOne` ? Is there something like or equivalent to  `product.category.id` ?

Comment: did you associate both the models?

Comment: i didn't change anything inside the models, i just generate them and as you see it generate the reference table inside the foreign key

Comment: you have to associate both the models... http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html 
 have a look

Comment: i will check it , but first can you explain to me the use of 'references' inside the atribute category ?

Comment: see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

if you have associated both the models... then try this

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('product', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            field: 'id'
        },
        category_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'category',
                key: 'id'
            },
            field: 'category'
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'name'
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'product'
    });
}

models.product.findOne({
    where: {
        id: req.body.id
    },
    include: [{
        model: category,
        required: false
      }]
}).then(function (obj) {
    //return the product data
    console.log(product.category) //works
    console.log(product.category.name) //return undefined
});
```

Associate like this

```
product.hasMany(db.category, {  
  foreignKey: 'category_id',
  onDelete: 'cascade'
});

category.belongsTo(db.product, {
  foreignKey: 'category_id',
  targetKey: 'id',
  constraints: true
});
```

Comment: before that how can i make the association ? please add it to your code

Comment: have a look again

Comment: got **Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
    at new BelongsTo**